# Avoid executing __init__ of mocked class

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I have a class with an expensive `__init__` function. I don't want this function called from tests.

For the purpose of this example, I made a class that raises an Exception in `__init__`:

```
class ClassWithComplexInit(object):

    def __init__(self):
        raise Exception("COMPLEX!")

    def get_value(self):
        return 'My value'
```

I have a second class that constructs an instance of `ClassWithComplexInit` and uses it's function.

```
class SystemUnderTest(object):

    def my_func(self):
        foo = ClassWithComplexInit()
        return foo.get_value()
```

I am trying to write some unit tests around `SystemUnderTest#my_func()`. The problem I am having is no matter how I try to mock `ClassWithComplexInit`, the `__init__` function always gets executed and the exception is raised.

```
class TestCaseWithoutSetUp(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('mypackage.ClassWithComplexInit.get_value', return_value='test value')
    def test_with_patched_function(self, mockFunction):
        sut = SystemUnderTest()
        result = sut.my_func()  # fails, executes ClassWithComplexInit.__init__()
        self.assertEqual('test value', result)

    @mock.patch('mypackage.ClassWithComplexInit')
    def test_with_patched_class(self, mockClass):
        mockClass.get_value.return_value = 'test value'
        sut = SystemUnderTest()
        result = sut.my_func()  # seems to not execute ClassWithComplexInit.__init__()
        self.assertEqual('test value', result)  # still fails
        # AssertionError: 'test value' != <MagicMock name='ClassWithComplexInit().get_value()' id='4436402576'>
```

The second approach above is one that I got from [this similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26547477/346561) but it didn't work either. It *seemed* to not run the `__init__` function but my assertion fails because the result ends up being a mock instance as opposed to my value.

I also tried to configure a `patch` instance in the `setUp` function, using the `start` and `stop` functions as [the docs suggest](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop).

```
class TestCaseWithSetUp(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.mockClass = mock.MagicMock()
        self.mockClass.get_value.return_value = 'test value'
        patcher = mock.patch('mypackage.ClassWithComplexInit', self.mockClass)
        patcher.start()
        self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)

    def test_my_func(self):
        sut = SystemUnderTest()
        result = sut.my_func()  # seems to not execute ClassWithComplexInit.__init__()
        self.assertEqual('test value', result)  # still fails
        # AssertionError: 'test value' != <MagicMock name='mock().get_value()' id='4554658128'>
```

This also seems to avoid my `__init__` function but the value I set for `get_value.return_value` isn't being respected and `get_value()` is still returning a `MagicMock` instance.

How can I mock a class with an complicated `__init__` which is instantiated by my code under test? Ideally, I would like a solution which works well for many unit tests within a TestCase class (e.g. Not needing to `patch` every test).

I am using Python version `2.7.6`.

Comment: How do you make `ClassWithComplexInit` available to your test script? `from mypackage import ClassWithComplexInit`, or something else?

Comment: @chepner My test script wasn't even importing `ClassWithComplexInit`. I switched a bunch of code from my real code to post here on SO and messed up the package references, I realize the reference are wrong. You address this in your answer though, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to use the same name you are patching to create `foo`, that is,

```
class SystemUnderTest(object):

    def my_func(self):
        foo = mypackage.ClassWithComplexInit()
        return foo.get_value()
```

Second, you need to configure the correct mock object. You are configuring `ClassWithComplexInit.get_value`, the unbound method, but you need to configure `ClassWithComplexInit.return_value.get_value`, which is the `Mock` object that will be actually be called with `foo.get_value()`.

```
@mock.patch('mypackage.ClassWithComplexInit')
def test_with_patched_class(self, mockClass):
    mockClass.return_value.get_value.return_value = 'test value'
    sut = SystemUnderTest()
    result = sut.my_func()  # seems to not execute ClassWithComplexInit.__init__()
    self.assertEqual('test value', result)  # still fails
```

Comment: This worked! I also came across this approach in [the docs for mocking chained calls](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#mocking-chained-calls). I was just about to post the solution myself, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Also, the expression `mockClass.return_value.get_value.return_value` can be replaced with `mockClass().get_value.return_value` and it still works.

Comment: Oh, right. The mock doesn't know that it is filling in for a class, so every "call" to `ClassWithComplexInit.__new__` is going to return the same object, and setting the return value of one object's `get_value()` method does so for all of them.